# trouble getting infinitely scrolling background to work

Tags: android, animation

Im attempting to get the back ground image for my program to scroll infinitely on its own but the code i am using isn't moving the image one bit

```
    final ImageView backgroundOne = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background_one);
    final ImageView backgroundTwo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background_two);

    final ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f, 1.0f);
    animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animator.setDuration(10000L);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            final float progress = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            final float width = backgroundOne.getWidth();
            final float translationX = width * progress;
            backgroundOne.setTranslationX(translationX);
            backgroundTwo.setTranslationX(translationX + width);
        }
    });
    animator.start();
```

Comment: @Rotwang Can you please help

Comment: I don't know much about Android animations. I don't use them.

Comment: Do you know someone who might

Comment: @cricket_007 i heard you know something about android

Comment: You can't address people who didn't leave a comment on your post. My suggestion is to dig the android developer site and the Google goldmine.